# creating a new instance of a class object box()

Tags: .net, vb.net

I there,
my aim is to create a new instance box at the push of a button, the box has strings name and Id to be filled concatenating the auto generated ID i.e. 0 to 210 plus a string "Box" added by the user.
I had problems earlier creating a structure within the class box, frankly I am not sure if the code below will work, as i try to run it in VB I get an error indicating that I am using the variables strBoxPositions() and strBoxNumbers() without assigning a value to it. 
The thing is the strBoxPositions() should automatically be filled by arrPosition() which will be created at the same time the new object box is created and the strNumbers() will be created with empty strings to be filled at latter stage by the used as and when necessary.

Could someone tell me how could I initialise those arrays to get the program to run and perhaps ill be able to see if the code works or not, or just correct this code with a better way of code with comments, also if possible some indication on how could I update the strNumbers array inputing the strings one at a time on a text box field.

Thanks for your help

```
Public class form1
    Public Class Box

        Public intBoxID As Integer
        Public strBoxName As String
        Structure positions
            Public strBoxPositions() As String
            Public strBoxNumbers() As String
        End Structure
        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal BoxID As Integer, ByVal BoxName As String)

            intBoxID = BoxID
            strBoxName = BoxName

        End Sub

    End Class

    Private Sub FormLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ArchiveBox() As Box = {}
        Dim arrLetters() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"}
        Dim arrNumbers() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}

        Dim arrPositions() As String '= New String() {}

        'GABE gave me this code earlier which works fine, thanks.       
        arrPositions = (From letter In arrLetters
        From number In arrNumbers
        Select letter + number).ToArray()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim BoxPositions As Box.positions
        Dim strSampleNr() As String = New String() {""}
        For i = 0 To 80

            ListBox1.Items.Add(arrPositions(i))
            BoxPositions.strBoxPositions(i) = arrPositions(i)
            BoxPositions.strBoxNumbers(i) = strSampleNr(i)

        Next
    End Sub
End class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays that are part of the structure positions are never initialized.  You should initialize them probably right after you Dim BoxPositions

If your arrPositions is the right number of items that you are actually wanting to put in the separate array then I would go with something like:

```
'this is to create new instances of the arrays used in the position structure
'Which is what was missed in your initial code.  It initializes the arrays as the same size as 
'your arrPositions

    BoxPositions.strBoxNumbers = New String(arrPositions.Length - 1) {}
    BoxPositions.strBoxPositions = New String(arrPositions.Length - 1) {}
```

That way you have an array of the right size prepared when you start the loop process.

However, the initial code for that loop still won't work because of the strSampleNr array not having the right size when you initialize it.

```
    Dim strSampleNr() As String = New String() {""}
```

Creates an array of string with a length of 1, since you didn't specify.

In any case, you need to initialize the array by using the keyword New on them before you start trying to access them inside the loop.  Trying to access an array that wasn't ever instantiated will cause the error you received.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code provided didn't really work. I have however been able to sort that out. I got the sub initialising and creating the positions and assigning it to the array as well as the empty spaces.  Dim ArchiveBox(1) As Box
Dim BoxPositions(81) As Box.positions
Dim arrPositions() As String
Dim i as integer
BoxPositions(i) = New Box.positions
For i = 0 To 80
BoxPositions(i).strBoxPositions = arrPositions(i)
BoxPositions(i).strBoxNumbers ="" ListBox1.Items.Add(BoxPositions(i).strBoxPositions)
ListBox1.Items.Add(BoxPositions(i).strBoxNumbers)
Next

Comment: What you did here has really altered things a bit.  When I answered you intially you had BoxPositions which was pointing to a structure that contained 2 arrays.  Now you have an array of position structures.  I think I am failing to understand what you are really trying to do.

Comment: What Im trying to achieve is this.

Comment: I want to create an empty container (box) with 81 empty positions. Ill update those positions on the go as I receive samples. I want to be able to create containers When the previous container gets all 81 positions filled. I want to be able to retrieve the information on all created containers when I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim ArchiveBox(1) As Box
    Dim BoxPositions(81) As Box.positions
    Dim arrLetters() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"}
    Dim arrNumbers() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
    Dim arrPositions() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    BoxPositions(i) = New Box.positions

     arrPositions = (From letter In arrLetters
     From number In arrNumbers
     Select letter + number).ToArray()

    For i = 0 To 80

        BoxPositions(i).strBoxPositions = arrPositions(i)
        BoxPositions(i).strBoxNumbers = ""
        ListBox1.Items.Add(BoxPositions(i).strBoxPositions)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(BoxPositions(i).strBoxNumbers)

    Next
```

Im trying now to find out how to access the BoxID and BoxName properties and assign it to a text box text, and then create and save an it every time a button is clicked.